# showing httpd.exe application error on server

Tags: php, apache

I am running online examination website on my localhost server. but when i have attached 8 another machines with LAN for conduct test. so it generate alert error message:-

> httpd.exe Application error
>
> The instruction at "0x006fb17f" referenced
> memory at "0x028a1e20". The memory could not be "Read".
>
> Click on OK to terminate.
>
> Click on Cancel to debug.

I am using PHP+MySQL on windows and XAMPP s/w installed at my server.

Is this message for my server RAM? Because my server RAM is 512 MB.

I can't understand. Can anybody help me, plz.

Comment: i would recommend you to ask this question on severfault.com project. it's not an insufficient memory issue. it's rather memory access problem

Answer (score 0):

Probably some virus on your XP. Try using IIS as a web-server or reinstall xampp or there is a new LAMP package called uniserver. Apache2 takes up lots of ram on windows this might effect PHP performance also.